# If System s = null then what will the output of below

Tags: java, system

I have the below code.

```
public static void main(String args[])
  {
    System s = null;
    s.out.println("Hello");
  }
```

I don't understand why the output is **Hello** though s is null. Could anyone help me to understand this?

Answer (score 6):

`System.out` is a static member of the type `System`.  This means that it doesn't require an instance to resolve; it only needs to know the type of `s` which is known to be `System`.

Being able to write `s.out` is just a convenience for `System.out`; most IDEs will throw a warning on this code.